# How can I add a reminder which contains a specific application in Reminders on Mac?

Tags: macos, notifications, application-launch, reminder

A few days ago, I created a reminder via Siri BY TYPING on Mac.（"Reminder me: ..."）

Accidentally, a Chrome browser icon appeared at the right of this reminder.
I was browsing a website on Chrome, this reminder automatically added the link of that web page in "notes".

Whenever I click on the icon, the computer will automatically open the web page that was viewed at that time, **even if the link in the notes has been deleted.**

What is this feature? How can I use it again?

[image: Reminders]
[image: The icon turned to Safari on iOS Reminders app.]
[image: Notification]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Attachments
>
> Add attachments to your reminders to make them more informative and useful. You can add photos, scanned documents or even web links that take you directly to a website related to the reminder.

<sup>From https://www.apple.com/in/macos/catalina/features/</sup>

Seems like it works for links to open browsers. Haven't tried photos and docs yet.